# naming a configuration property function

Tags: msbuild

I have a project that has a set of project contexts (full property groups omitted for brevity):

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'v82_Release|x64' ">
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'v90_Release|x64' ">
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'v90_Debug|x64' ">
```

The referenced assemblies vary by the version number at the beginning of the configuration
variable, so I opened the VS-generated csproj file and edited the references (parent `Reference` items omitted for brevity):

```
<HintPath>Lib\$(Configuration.Substring(0,3))\Assembly1.dll</HintPath>
<HintPath>Lib\$(Configuration.Substring(0,3))\Assembly2.dll</HintPath>
<HintPath>Lib\$(Configuration.Substring(0,3))\Assembly3.dll</HintPath>
```

This works, but is there a way to effectively define `$(LibVersionNum) = $(Configuration.Substring(0,3))` and thus clean up my syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <Configuration>v82_Release</Configuration>
        <Platform>x64</Platform>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'v82_Release|x64' ">

    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'v90_Release|x64' ">

    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'v90_Debug|x64' ">

    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup>
        <LibVersionNum>$(Configuration.Substring(0,3))</LibVersionNum>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <MyItem Include="Ref1">
            <HintPath>Lib\$(LibVersionNum)\Assembly1.dll</HintPath>
        </MyItem>
        <MyItem Include="Ref2">
            <HintPath>Lib\$(LibVersionNum)\Assembly2.dll</HintPath>
        </MyItem>
        <MyItem Include="Ref3">
            <HintPath>Lib\$(LibVersionNum)\Assembly3.dll</HintPath>
        </MyItem>
    </ItemGroup>

    <Target Name="Build">
        <Message Text="Current Config: $(Configuration)"/>
        <Message Text="%(MyItem.Identity): %(MyItem.HintPath)"/>
    </Target>
</Project>
```